# AWS EC2 is Randomly Duplicating Instances and Messing Things Up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Ok, this is an odd one. Here's the behaviour I've experienced which seems random when this happens and I can only assume this is down to some magic in the background of AWS workings.

1. The server becomes inaccessible both via the browsers friendly Route53 URL such as https://my.route53powered.dns.website.com, but remains accessible with the IP address
2. Then naturally I start to investigate what is going on, and notice within the EC2 Dashbaord within AWS, that a blank instance has been created with a new InstanceID, iid999, which sits alongside the default InstanceID, iid123. Odd. As this wasn't created manually. When looking at this new instance that has been created, it has its own static IP address (Elastic IP), and when I click on that, it showed the duplicate name of the original instance - suggesting this is s duplicate copy of the instance that has happened in the background.
3. After a short time, around 10-15 minutes, the new instance that was automatically created gets deleted.

Throughout this time, the original instance remains down. Can't access via friendly Route53 URL, can't access over SSH (the connection is mainly down, with around 10% of the time being intermittent access with various errors such as the server booting out the SSH session, the server not accepting the SSH Key).

Also, while all this is happening, the main EC2 instance is always listed as "Running" in the EC2 console. And doesn't seem to make a difference when I restart the instance either. It still takes a bit of time to work again.

What is going on? I've not managed to find any other reports on this online so I've also raised a support request with AWS directly.

Comment: Check if you have any autoscaling groups?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I've just checked and there are some autoscaling groups, but none related to this instance in question. After speaking with AWS they believe is it related to a spike in CPU utilisation, but I'm not convinced.